# How to create a new group in a grid view and add items to it?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

```
// Create a new grid view, add content, 
GridView gridView1 = new GridView();
gridView1.Items.Add("Item 1");
gridView1.Items.Add("Item 2");

// Add the grid view to a parent container in the visual tree.
stackPanel1.Children.Add(gridView1);
```

How to create a new group in gridView1 and add items to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove groups in the grid view and manage it easily by binding a data source.
When you change the data source , grid view will automatically refresh its contents.
To get the basic understanding , analyze the Grid App(XAML) project template provided under Visual C# section of the "New Project" dialog.